# Why no sshd logs on Stackdriver?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

On a GCP Compute Engine instance, OS is Ubuntu 18.04, Stackdriver logging agent is installed.

Any idea why Stackdriver doesn't ingest `auth.log` by default? What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up simply adding an additional entry in `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf`

```
<source>
  @type tail

  # Parse the timestamp, but still collect the entire line as 'message'
  format /^(?<message>(?<time>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]* [^ ]*) .*)$/

  path /var/log/auth.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/auth.log.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag auth
</source>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Additionally, pay attention to the amount of data that the SSH server logs. Every hacker trying to log into your server via SSH will be logged. This can create a large amount of data written to Stackdriver.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not on 22 and I have fail2ban running ;)

Comment: I am not correcting your answer; I am adding information to your answer for future readers. They may not realize how much traffic can be generated over port 22.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is that The VM images for Compute Engine don't include the Logging agent by default. To answer your second question, You need to install the Stackdriver Logging agent on your VM. Please follow the information and instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation). I could reproduce that to ensure it works. After installing the agent, you will be able to see SSH connections in Stackdriver Logging, for example, their header looks like this: "..session opened for user USER". It also logs when the SSH session is closed; its header looks like this: "...session closed for user USER".

Comment: I have the agent installed. I'm seeing log entries from syslog, but not for auth. Did you change something in sshd_config ?

Comment: @Rhangaun I’m not sure if this is by default. Though, I’m curious, would you share the OS info as to verify that?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Rhangaun, I see you have submitted an answer which ended up the issue by adding an additional entry in /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf. If you still have issues, please post more details about your use case and the issue.